# What is meant by the equation $\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=8$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For this question, **I was thinking the answer to part A is option A, and part B is either option A or C**?

[image]

Comment: I think the answers are A and A

Comment: Your part $B$ basically talks about removable discontinuity..

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first one is A,it is basically (informal) definition of limit,answer to B is A as statement should be only true when $f$ is continuous at $3$,but it can be discontinuous at $3$.

Comment: So option A for answer be would be incorrect?

Comment: Yes in both cases option A's  are correct.